# x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, go, x509

I'm trying some basic examples to request data from the web, however all requests to different hosts result in an SSL error: `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. **Note**: I'm not behind a proxy and no forms of certificate interception is happening, as using curl or the browser works without problems.

The code sample I'm currently working with is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    )

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
    }
}
```

Edit: Code is run on Arch linux kernel 4.9.37-1-lts.

**Edit 2**: Apparently `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` had a difference between the version on my system, by (re)moving the certificate and re-installing the `ca-certificates-utils` package manually, the issue was solved.

Comment: Your code runs perfectly on my local machine. Are you running the directly in the machine or inside any container?

Comment: this code runs fine inside a Ubuntu docker container

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux kernel version 4.9.37-1-lts. Code is working fine on any other machine, however not on this machine.

Comment: @MaicoTimmerman How did you solve that? I've the same issue

Comment: Please see my final edit, I moved the certificate and reinstalled the ca-certificates-utils manually.

Comment: I'm using `go-pingdom` package and running on docker `alpine:3.8`. I don't have anything under `/etc/ssl/certs`. I have tried to install `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual ca-certificates-utils` but without any luck.

Answer (score 10):

Based on your error, I'm assuming you are using Linux?

It's likely that you will have to install ca-certificates on the machine your program is running on.

On Ubuntu, you would execute something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: First of all, I'm on arch linux and I've got the ca-certificates installed:
`pacaur -Qsq ca-certificates` results in

`ca-certificates
ca-certificates-cacert
ca-certificates-mozilla
ca-certificates-utils
`

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` as this package almost certainly is installed

Comment: Thank you all, worked for me on debian 10  "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates" !