# x509 certificate signed by unknown authority - go-pingdom

Tags: http, docker, go, x509

I'm using the Go package `pingdom-go` to query Pingdom. The application is containerized as this:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

USER nobody

ADD build/_output/bin/app /usr/local/bin/app
```

However I get the following error:

```
Get https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.1/checks/0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've already tried what suggested here [x509 certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165813/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority#45165813) but without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to install ca-certificates: `apk add --no-cache ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the `alpine` containers are very minimal, including not having certs. You can either install the certs like @TimCooper suggested:

```
apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
```

You can also checkout [GoogleContainerTools/distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless). It is minimal but has a few things like certs that make development life a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

add the following cmd to your Dockerfile can fix it.

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```