# docker multi-stage build Go image - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, go, docker-multi-stage-build, go-build, go-git

I try to build [go](/questions/tagged/go) images in ***private corp*** network use [docker-multi-stage-build](/questions/tagged/docker-multi-stage-build):

```
FROM golang:latest as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN  GO111MODULE="on" CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ${MAIN_PATH}

FROM alpine:latest
LABEL maintainer="Kozmo"
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

and get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error

```
Step 1/13 : FROM golang:latest as builder
 ---> 2421885b04da
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6555644dbd16
Step 3/13 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> 55d45a30f492
Step 4/13 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Running in 88c21c6b4fab
go: github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4@v4.0.0-preview1: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4/@v/v4.0.0-preview1.mod": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 1
make: *** [docker] Error 1
```

I tried to find an answer in

> [X509: Certificate Signed by Unknown Authority (Running a Go App
> Inside a Docker Container)](https://medium.com/the-go-journey/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-running-a-go-app-inside-a-docker-container-a12869337eb)

and

> [docker build: cannot get the github public repository, x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35702)

and

> [x509 certificate signed by unknown authority - go-pingdom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53211703/8030651)

, but result is the same.

---

❗️If add `-insecure` flag

```
...
RUN go env -w GOPROXY=direct GOFLAGS="-insecure"
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
...
```

to `Dockerfile`  `unrecognized import path` error ***wrap*** previous `x509` error and an *unreachable*  package change to `golang.org/x/crypto`

```
go: golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20200622213623-75b288015ac9: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto": https fetch: Get "https://golang.org/x/crypto?go-get=1": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

What is the problem❓

(I understand that problem is in the certificates and authentication when `git` get dependencies, but I try to make process of building images more common)

Comment: Did you try to restart docker.service in client?

Comment: @ Ashok  - zero result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [x509 certificate signed by unknown authority - go-pingdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211703/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-go-pingdom)

Comment: @ Peter  - When I use `golang:latest` I get `The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache ca-certificates' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: @ Peter - When I use `golang:alpine` I get `go: github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4@v4.0.0-preview1: git init --bare in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/dbb1616a13223a75321e21a8150b1a7781650b73e761213ecc0ab67568c38ac2: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: Try to add this in your dockerfile RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

Comment: @ Ashok - in `golang:latest` ➡️ `/bin/sh -c The command ... returned a non-zero code: 127` and in `golang:alpine` ➡️  `exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: I think the given command is not found within your PATH system variable. The system doesn't understand your command, because it doesn't know where to find the binary you're trying to call.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`git` uses `curl` to access the `https` servers so you need to import the certificate into the `CA store` of the system.

The workaround is to define the environment variable `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1` on your Agent environment variables, **but it doesn't work when using `go get` or `go mod download`** .

To import the certificate on your system CA store the procedure depends on your OS you have to use `openssl`.

For example

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates openssl

ARG cert_location=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates

# Get certificate from "github.com"
RUN openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > ${cert_location}/github.crt
# Get certificate from "proxy.golang.org"
RUN openssl s_client -showcerts -connect proxy.golang.org:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >  ${cert_location}/proxy.golang.crt
# Update certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN  GO111MODULE="on" CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ${MAIN_PATH}

FROM alpine:latest
LABEL maintainer="Kozmo"
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

`docker image build` output

```
...

Step 5/19 : RUN openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > ${cert_location}/github.crt
 ---> Running in bb797e26d4b4
Removing intermediate container bb797e26d4b4
 ---> 6c68ddafd884
Step 6/19 : RUN openssl s_client -showcerts -connect proxy.golang.org:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >  ${cert_location}/proxy.golang.crt
 ---> Running in 61f59939d75e
Removing intermediate container 61f59939d75e
 ---> 72d2b03b11e6
Step 7/19 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in 6cf9aa248776
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
2 added, 0 removed; done.  'certificates updated'

...

Step 8/18 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> 436263b76050
Step 9/18 : RUN go mod download  'works fine'
 ---> Running in 2387c78147db
Removing intermediate container 2387c78147db
 ---> a37c05c2b531
Step 10/18 : COPY . .
 ---> 01b49c388f59

...
```

Answer (score 9):

I'll suggest a couple of things:

- Build your code within the same OS distribution as the final code image, so that you are sure that your code will run in that specific distribution. Also some distributions require certs to be in different folders, so be aware of that.
- Using alpine for the first image will substantially decrease your build time. You can see [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/golang/library/golang/latest/images/sha256-4e484a5b15a5773a44fc305205b7d3bd3222382eb900959c59897fd38d979899?context=explore) `latest` size is ~260M, but `alpine` is ~100M.
- Better will be to use an specific version of alpine, so that you can be sure that your code runs in that version (I leave this at your discretion)
- Something very powerful of Golang is that you can run it in an empty docker image called `scratch`, this means, your final docker images does not contain more than your own executable.
- If you need your own certificates you must have them in your code and copy them before executing `update-ca-certificates` so that they get included in the final file

Here's an example of the dockerfile with what I explained above

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

# This will download all certificates (ca-certificates) and builds it in a
# single file under /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt (update-ca-certificates)
# I also add git so that we can download with `go mod download` and
# tzdata to configure timezone in final image
RUN apk --update add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl git tzdata && \
update-ca-certificates

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN  GO111MODULE="on" CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ${MAIN_PATH}

# Golang can run in a scratch image, so that, the only thing that your docker 
# image contains is your executable
FROM scratch
LABEL maintainer="Kozmo"
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/zoneinfo /usr/share/zoneinfo

# This line will copy all certificates to final image
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

If own certificates replace first docker stage with:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk --update add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl git tzdata

COPY your/cert/path /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/your-cert-name

RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN  GO111MODULE="on" CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ${MAIN_PATH}
```

Because you use own certificates your final `Dockerfile` will look like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk --update add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl git tzdata

COPY your/cert/path /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/your-cert-name

RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN  GO111MODULE="on" CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ${MAIN_PATH}

FROM scratch
LABEL maintainer="Kozmo"
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/zoneinfo /usr/share/zoneinfo

# This line will copy all certificates to final image
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

Feel free to ask me if you have any doubt :)

Comment: I have the same error (`x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`) on the step `RUN go mod download` because I try to built image in **private**  corp network. In  our company we can use `nexus` as `go proxy`, maybe I have to try to build image through `nexus`....

Comment: Do you have any suggestions why I get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` use `Dockerfile` as you offered❓

Comment: Have you copied certificates as explained in the second part? Also I forgot to mention that they need to be `.pem` format in order for `update-ca-certificates` to picke them up and add them to the trusted certs

Comment: if I use `golang:latest as builder` and copy self certificates (look at ***my*** answer)  It works, but when I try to use `Dockerfile` like ***your first example*** I have got an error: `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: I mean copying your own certificates as the second part of my answer. Copying them to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` in the stage `golang:latest as builder`

Comment: Second part of your answer ***works***, but what about first part?l Could I generate certificates automatically every build?

Comment: As I posted in my answer, the second part is the replacement of the first docker stage if you use your own certificates. I have added a third part which will be your final docker file using your own certificates

Comment: Is the github.crt you are copying the official github crt, or a self own certificate? I'm wondering if the issue then becomes on the private corp layer. Does your corp has CA roots certs?

Comment: I have ca-certificate.crt in docker image, but getting "Could not send Email Alert ! x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match" error

Answer (score 4):

Coping self certificates (`.crt`) helped

1️⃣ add `.crt` to required `dir`

```
.
└── backend
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── Makefile
    ├── cmd
    │   └── main.go
    ├── etc
    │   ├── ssl
    │   │   └── github.crt #❗️a copy of the self certificate
```

2️⃣ `COPY` certificates to 'builder'-container

```
FROM golang:latest as builder
COPY  etc/ssl/ /etc/ssl/certs/ #❗️add certificates to the container 
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
```

---

Answer (score 1):

From your error message

> Get
> "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4/@v/v4.0.0-preview1.mod":
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

It looks like the CA root of proxy.golang.org is not part of the trusted root CAs in your private corp docker environment.

I'd try to install it with :

1 - Get the certificate from proxy.golang.org :

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect proxy.golang.org:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ./golang.cer
```

If you open golang.cer you should see the certificates chain

[image]

2 - install it in your trusted root CAs :

```
certutil.exe -addstore root golang.cer
```

...or on Mac :

2a - Double click the certificate file (with ".cer" extension)

2b - Choose "System" from the keychain option. Then press "OK"

2c - When the following window pops-up, click the "Always Trust" button.

Comment: Add `install it in your trusted root CAs ...` for mac/nix, please

Answer (score 0):

## Docker-Private-Registry

Creating your own Private Docker Registry (Ubuntu 18.04 Linux) with self signed TLS Certificate

Pre-Req : Ubuntu VM with Docker-CE Edition installed on it and required ports open to the outside world (or as required)

Add your Ubuntu VM IP address in subjectAltName in the openssl.cnf before generating certficates

```
sudo vi /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Add the following with your VM specific IP address under the section [ v3_ca ]

```
[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName=IP:IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM
```

Create a local folder which will hold the certificates and that can be referenced by the Docker Registry server

```
mkdir -p /certificates

cd certificates

openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt
  
#Enter all required fields (it could be anything) but please enter your Server IP address when it prompts for -> Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)

Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM

# Check if the certificates are created in the current directory (certificates)

ls
```

Launch Docker registry using version 2 and referencing the certificates folder for TLS

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v /certificates:/certificates \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certificates/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certificates/domain.key \
  registry:2
  
docker ps
docker logs CONTAINER-ID

#Check & proceed further if there are no errors in the registry container log
```

To verify our Docker registry, let us pull a small hello-world docker image from Docker-Hub registry, tag it appropriately and try to push it to our local Registry

```
docker pull hello-world
docker tag hello-world IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM:5000/hello-world

docker push IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM:5000/hello-world
```

Certificate Error? Docker Server does not trust the self-signed certificate and our certificates need to be manually added to Docker Engine

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM:5000

#Please make sure to copy domain.crt as ca.crt (or rename later on) 
sudo cp /certificates/domain.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM:5000/ca.crt

sudo ls /etc/docker/certs.d/IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VM:5000/

#reload docker daemon to use the ca.crt certificate
sudo service docker reload
```

Try pushing to the local registry server now!!